# About nested resources with just resources in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, nested-routes

The problem is i want to have both nested resources and normal resources pointing the the same action in controller but act differently based on whether the nesting resource in available or not.

> Routes.rb

```
 resources :users do
     resources :comments  //For having nested routes
 end
 resources :comments  //For having normal routes
```

## Nested Resource

For example

> Class CommentsController < ApplicationController

```
 def index
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   @comment = @user.comments.find(params[:id])
 end
```

Now,

If i want to just look up all the comments , i want to use the

> /comments

Else if i am in the user page and click on the all comments i get to

> /user/:user_id/comments

Hence, how to configure to make sure it generates the right page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would do like this:

```
def index
  @comment = Comment.find_by(user_id: params[:user_id], id: params[:id])

  # It looked weird that you tried to find a @comment
  # instead of @comments in action `index`
  # I think you made a typing mistake and this can be help
  @comments = Comment.where(user_id: params[:user_id])
end
```